# Getting user info from LDAP by using JAVA

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

For LDAP, I use LDAP test server namely as [Forumsys](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) and we can see users and groups of Forumsys LDAP in [the link](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjvjMShsofXAhUiIJoKHV7QBZIQFghBMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdirex.azurewebsites.net%2Fhome%2Fconnect%3Fhost%3Dldap.forumsys.com%26port%3D389%26baseDn%3Ddc%3Dexample%2Cdc%3Dcom%26userDn%3Dcn%3Dread-only-admin%2Cdc%3Dexample%2Cdc%3Dcom%26password%3Dpassword&usg=AOvVaw18GaH8UY3_WeFaqdnD2vE6).

I want to get users' info from their groups. I watched some videos about LDAP on JAVA and tried to do. However, I cannot get them. My code returns null.

How can I solve it? Where is my problem in getting the users' and groups' information?

This my code:

```
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;

import java.util.Hashtable;



public class LDAPV2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException{
        Hashtable <String,String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389/dc=example,dc=com");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=boyle,dc=example,dc=com");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

        DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);
        DirContext groupCx = (DirContext) context.lookup("ou=chemists");


        NamingEnumeration <Binding> groups = groupCx.listBindings("");
        while (groups.hasMore()){
            String bindingName = groups.next().getName();
            Attributes groupAttributes = groupCx.getAttributes(bindingName);
            Attribute groupName=groupAttributes.get("cn");
            System.out.println(groupName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ou=chemists` is empty in the directory you're looking up. So it has no child bindings, so the `while` loop never executes.

It does however have some *attributes*, which you can print with:

```
    Attributes groupAttributes = groupCx.getAttributes("");
    Attribute groupName = groupAttributes.get("uniqueMember");
    System.out.println(groupName);
```